# ListView inside FlipView - Scroll Behavior

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have this setup:

```
<FlipView>
  <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <ListView />
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </FlipViewItem>
</FlipView>
```

With Mouse it works good without any errors.

But with Touch it scrolls in both directions (horizontal and vertical), what I like to have would be the same behavior the WinRT Start Menu (if you start scrolling in the horizontal "line", you can only scroll on this, even If you start swiping vertically it the Y Axes stays the same.)

I've been searching a full month for a solution, without any luck, seems that I'm the only one who wants something like that.

Things I've tried till now:

- ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled / .IsVerticalRailEnabled
- Catch Manipulation Events on List- / FlipView
- ScrollViewer.ViewChanged
- even tried some hacks but none of them worked

I hope someone has an Idea / a Solution^^

Comment: I don't get what your problem is. Can you give some more information? Your XAML seems to be wrong (closing tag FlipViewItem).

Comment: Example View: http://pastebin.com/vzFC1B2H

If you tried it on a Touch Device, you'll see that it can scroll in both directions, and then look at the Win8.1 Start Menu, there you can onl scroll in one direction at a time

Comment: I doubt that you can suppress this behavior. I've a similar situation and I didn't find a solution yet. I guess Win8.1 uses two different containers which grow horizontal and not vertical. Therefore they can disable vertical scrolling within the container.